# why do i need 2 parameters for callback?

Tags: json, file, parsing, fs

i have a simlple asynchronious reader in a node-script reading firefox-json-bookmarks.
when i remove the first parameter (err) in the callback function, i got an error.
what is the reason? And why is err different from e?

app.js

```
var fs = require('fs'), obj;
fs.readFile(__dirname + '/bookmarks.json', 'utf8', handleFile);

function handleFile( err, data ) { // why is the first parameter needed?

    try {
        obj = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify(data) );
        console.log(obj);

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        //console.log(err);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.joyent.com/developers/node/design/errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you call a function, that function is pushed onto a stack of functions known as the call stack. When that function returns a value, it is popped off the stack. The call stack describes where you are in your program and how you got there.

### Synchronous Code

Imagine the call stack through out the course of this program.

```
function a() { return b() }
function b() { return c() }
function c() { throw new Error() }
a();
```

First, `a` is called, so we add it to the stack.

```
[ a ]
```

Then `a` calls `b`, so we add that to the stack too.

```
[ a, b ]
```

Then `b` calls `c`.

```
[ a, b, c ]
```

Then `c` throws an error. At this point, the debugger can tell you that `c` was the function that threw the error and that you ended up at `c`, via `a` then `b`. This works fine for regular synchronous code, like `JSON.parse`.

### Asynchronous Code

Asynchronous code continues to run after the function has returned. For instance:

```
function a() {
  setTimeout(function() { console.log(2); }, 10000);
  return 1;
}
```

If you call `a`, then it will be pushed onto the call stack, then return `1` and be popped off the call stack. About 10 seconds later `2` will be printed into the console.

What would happen if the timeout did this instead?

```
function a() {
  setTimeout(function() { throw new Error(); }, 10000);
  return 1;
}
```

The error would be thrown, but the call stack would be empty. As you can imagine, this isn't very useful for developers.

This is also a problem if we want to return a value asynchronously. By the time the async stuff happens (timeout, read/write, network etc), the function has already returned.

Instead, we can use a form of what's known as [Continuation-Passing Style](http://matt.might.net/articles/by-example-continuation-passing-style/), mostly referred to as *callbacks*. As well as calling our asynchronous function, we also pass it function (a continuation), which we ask it to run when it has finished. Remember, this can be after the function has returned a value!

In Node.js, these callbacks serve two purposes:

#### Errors

If an error occurs whilst doing the asynchronous work, standard practice is to call the callback with the error as the first argument. You'll often see the following code.

```
foo.doAsyncBar(function(err, baz) {
  if(err) throw err;
  // do something with baz
});
```

By passing the error the callback rather than throwing it, we are able to make our own decisions about how best to handle it. We can just throw it, as shown above, or we can handle it in a more graceful way.

#### Return

Hopefully, the function won't error, in which case, the general practice is to pass `null` as the first argument to the callback. This lets the developer writing the handling code know that the function didn't error and that the return value is in one of the next arguments.

For a more in depth article on Node.js error handling, see Joyent's [Production Practices document for Errors](https://www.joyent.com/developers/node/design/errors).

Comment: thank you. but is it ok, when i do not throw the error and only do:                 if (err) return console.error(err);    ?

Comment: It depends. This way you'll see the error, but the program could potentially stop working without crashing — you might start to lose data. If you throw the error, then you're guaranteed the program will stop. If it's a non-critical error, then you could use `console.warn` and be explicit about it instead.